# How can I concatenate multiple text or xml files but omit specific lines from each file?

Tags: python, xml, linux, bash

I have a number of xml files (which can be considered as text files in this situation) that I wish to concatenate.  Normally I think I could do something like this from a Linux command prompt or bash script:

```
cat somefile.xml someotherfile.xml adifferentfile.xml > out.txt
```

Except that in this case, I need to copy the first file in its entirety EXCEPT for the very last line, but in all subsequent files omit exactly the first four lines and the very last line (technically, I do need the last line from the last file but it is always the same, so I can easily add it with a separate statement).

In all these files the first four lines and the last line are always the same, but the contents in between varies.  The names of the xml files can be hardcoded into the script or read from a separate data file, and the number of them may vary from time to time but always will number somewhere around 10-12.

I'm wondering what would be the easiest and most understandable way to do this.  I think I would prefer either a bash script or maybe a python script, though I generally understand bash scripts a little better.  What I can't get my head around is how to trim off just those first four lines (on all but the first file) and the last line of every file.  My suspicion is there's some Linux command that can do this, but I have no idea what it would be.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Look into the command lines tools `tail` and `head`.

Comment: You can also use `sed` intuitively: to delete 1-4th line + last line: `sed '1,4d; $d'`.

Comment: treating xml files like a common text files is the wrong approach in my opinion. what if the formatting of the xml file changes? use appropriate xml tools like xmllint instead. have a look at http://softwaretester.info/test-xml-command-line-with-xmllint/

Comment: In this case the format of the files will never change (if they ever do then I have much bigger issues to worry about), and I really didn't want to get into dealing with xml file syntax, when treating the files as text files is much easier and something I might be able to understand.  I almost didn't even mention that they were xml files because I feared getting this type of response.  As for tail and head, I figured how how tail can be used to strip the first four lines (tail -n +5 ...) but I don't see how head can be used to keep all but the last line.

Comment: use sed like @PesaThe wrote. $d is always the last line. I still wonder what you do with text file afterwards...

Comment: sed '1,4d; $d' appears to work perfectly.  Thank you PesaThe!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed '$d' firstfile > out.txt
sed --separate '1,4d; $d' file2 file3 file4 >> out.txt
sed '1,4d' lastfile >> out.txt
```

It's important to use the `--separate` (or shorter `-s`) option so that the range statements `1,4` and `$` apply to each file individually.

From GNU `sed` [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Command_002dLine-Options):

> `-s`, `--separate`
>
> By default, `sed` will consider the files specified on the command line as a single continuous long stream. This GNU `sed`
> extension allows the user to consider them as separate files.

Answer (score 0):

Do it in two steps:

1. use the head command (to get the lines you want)
2. Use cat to combine

You could use temp files or bash trickery.